# Combining SET statements with normal statements

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to create a tool that runs mySQL queries/ statements on a database.
The problem I'm running into is that these queries/ statements are in a free form text like a text box - I'm also using them with a professional SQL program.
To give an example it would be something like:

```
#Example of a query statement
@SET fName = "John"
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Person.firstName = fName

#Example of an execute statement
@SET fName = "John"
DELETE FROM Person WHERE Person.firstName = fName
```

As you can see the query/ statements may contain comments, SET statements and then either an execute statement or a select query. Also they may not always be properly formatted so there may be empty lines between stuff or tabs or spaces.

I know about the option with PreparedStatements, but while that would work it doesn't really fit the bill of the whole query/ statement being editable as freeform text.
My question is how to execute these statements/ queries through Java? executeBatch would work for the second example, but not the first as it's returning a ResultSet.

Comment: You need to look at using `execute()`, make sure you disable auto-commit.

Comment: Does .setAutoCommit(false) allow stacking of executed statements?
Would only .execute() work on "@SET xxxx"
If I split the statements up and run either .executeUpdate() or .executeQuery() with .setAutoCommit(false) will it allow me to stack them and commit them after they've all executed?

Comment: I don't regularly use MySQL, and I have never used `@SET`, however I would expect those not to be persisted across commit boundaries (I might be wrong though). You need to use [`execute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-) because you don't know what type of statement you're executing in advance. And yes, when you disable auto-commit, you need to call `commit()` yourself on the connection object.

Comment: Thanks that's helped. I'll try to work it out tomorrow and see if it works.

Comment: Please read the [JDBC apidoc of `execute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-) and related methods. The return value of `execute` is a boolean. If it is `true`, then it means the first result is a `ResultSet` and you can get it with `getResultSet`, if it is `false` the first result is an update count which you can get with `getUpdateCount`. In some database you can have more results. You can use `getMoreResults` in a similar way (if `execute/getMoreResults` is `false` and update count is `-1` then there are no more results).

Comment: I will see if I can make time to make a real answer out of those. But feel free to answer your own question with the solution you used :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution comes out to using Statement.execute() rather than one of the more specific functions like .executeUpdate() or .executeQuery() or even .executeBatch()

The function .execute() returns a boolean to say whether there are results returned or if there are more results to get.

```
public void executeAll(String queryString) throws SQLException {
    boolean hasMoreResults = statement.execute(queryString);
    int updateCount = statement.getUpdateCount();

    while(hasMoreResults || (!hasMoreResults && updateCount != -1)){
        //.execute() can be false if a query is not returned as when using a SET/ UPDATE/ DELETE which is why we check if updateCount is -1 meaning there are no more statements returned
        if(hasMoreResults){
            resultSet = statement.getResultSet();
            //Do what you need to do with the ResultSet
        } else {
            //Else it's a UPDATE/ DELETE count - int
            //Do what you need to do with the updateCount
        }
        hasMoreResults = statement.getMoreResults();
        updateCount = statement.getUpdateCount();
        //New values for the next cycle
    }
    //Possibly return stuff?
}
```